# Oddities in Configuring Vim

Tags: shell, vim, configuration, keymapping

Vim is exhibiting some configuration behaviors that confuse me.

1. I have read that vim accepts `$VIM/vimrc` as its default configuration file. In my shell environment, `$VIM` is set to `/etc/vim`, but `/etc/vim/vimrc` is not used as the default config file. Rather, `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` is used.
2. I have defined the following mapping in my vimrc file (which is now `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`), `nnoremap ccom :normal I//< ESC>< CR>`. This map is supposed to insert a c-style comment at the beginning of the current line. When I use this map, I get the text `//<ESC><CR>` put at the beginning of the current line. This is a malfunction. Similarly, if I start vim with `-u /usr/share/vim/vimrc`, the mapping exhibits the same undesirable behavior. If, however, I use the ex command `source /usr/share/vim/vimrc`, the mapping simply inserts `//` at the beginning of the line. How can this be?
3. Why isn't showcmd set if `:show cmd` is in a configuration file that I know ran?

Comment: No, your vimrc is *not* `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`, it's `~/.vimrc`, which is accessible also from within Vim with `:e $MYVIMRC`. You need to create it yourself if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: **If you have more than one question, ask more than one question.** `:show cmd` does nothing whether you do it in Vim at runtime or in your `~/.vimrc`. Use `:set showcmd` at runtime or add `set showcmd` to your `~/.vimrc`. Oh! And read `:help showcmd`.

Answer (score 1):

***NEVER*** do anything in `$VIM`.

*All* your configuration is supposed to happen in the `~/.vim` directory and the `~/.vimrc` file.

Put this line in `~/.vimrc` and you are good to go:

```
nnoremap ccom :normal I//<CR>
```

*edit*

`$VIM` is Vim's default runtime. As such, it is setup in a way that guarantees a consistent user experience. Here are three good reasons, I'm sure I could dig up a few more:

- Changing anything in that directory simply puts Vim in an inconsistent state that *may* lead to unexpected behaviors.
- The content (or parts of the content) of that directory may be overwritten during the next upgrade (vim or system), essentially wiping out any customization you have done there.
- Most script are designed around a bunch of conventions and generally require that some features are accessible at run time or source time or whatever. Installing those scripts anywhere else than their normal location (`~/.vim`) is going to lead to more unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Why do you advise against doing anything in $VIM?